# Equivalent of redis-cli MEMORY USAGE <key> in Spring Boot using redisTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I'm currently trying to monitor memory used by an embedded Redis in my Spring Boot app. I found the equivalent of the "info memory" command using RedisTemplate, giving general memory usage information. However, it didn't find a way to have more specific memory usage information related to a key which is the equivalent of using the command MEMORY USGAE  with redis-cli. Is there a way to get this information programmatically using RedisTemplate ?

There is no redis installed locally on my desktop, and I don't have the rights to install it myself, that's why I have to use an embedded redis.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

RedisTemplate does not have this API, you can use the `EVAL` command to get the output of this.

Key and Script

```
String script = "return redis.pcall('MEMORY', 'USAGE', KEYS[1])";
String key = "test";
```

Simple Using RedisConnectionUtils

```
    RedisConnection redisConnection =
        RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory());
    
    System.out.println(
        (Long)
            (redisConnection.eval(
                script.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                ReturnType.INTEGER,
                1,
                key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
     RedisConnectionUtils.releaseConnection(
        redisConnection, redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory());
```

Using pipeline to get the same result.

```
System.out.println(
        redisTemplate
            .executePipelined(
                (RedisCallback<Object>)
                    connection -> {
                      connection.eval(
                          script.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                          ReturnType.INTEGER,
                          1,
                          jobsKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                      return null;
                    })
            .get(0));
```

Comment: Which version of Spring do you use ? When I tried to execute the command and I got an unknown script exception. I use Spring Boot 2.2.8 and Spring Data Moore-SR8.

Comment: Can you share the complete stack trace on pastebinI'm using  spring 2.1.x .

Comment: @MatJeg did you miss to add `String script = "return redis.pcall('MEMORY', 'USAGE', KEYS[1])";` in code?

Comment: I added the script, I have the following exception : redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException : @user_script: 1: Unknown Redis command called from Lua script

Comment: see if your Redis server supports this command.